# How do you create an EVP_KEY for a peer key given the Base64 encoding?

Tags: c++, openssl, diffie-hellman

Using OpenSSL, I've created my Diffie-Hellman Private/Public keys and received my peer's public key.  I can decode my peer's key from Base64 string to byte array, but how do I poke that into my original Public/Private Key EVP_KEY structure so it can be used with the EVP_PKEY_derive() to produce the shared key?

It's very unclear exactly what one should do to create the "peerkey" EVP_PKEY, but here's my code that takes a shot at it.

```
void CreateSharedKey(string &peerKey64)
{
    EVP_PKEY *publicKey;  // Created earlier
    EVP_PKEY *peerKey;

    // Decode peer key
    unsigned char *pBuff;
    int buffLen = base64Decode(peerKey64, &pBuff);
    const unsigned char *pConst = pBuff;

    // Create peer key
    peerKey = d2i_PUBKEY(NULL, &pConst, buffLen);
    if (peerKey == NULL)
        return;

    // Create shared key context
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctxShared;
    ctxShared = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(publicKey, NULL);
    if (ctxShared == NULL)
        return;

    // Initialize for deriving shared key
    if (EVP_PKEY_derive_init(ctxShared) <= 0)
        return;

    // Add peer key to context
    if (int rc = EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(ctxShared, peerKey) <= 0)
        return;

    // Determine buffer length for shared key
    size_t sharedKeyBufferSize;
    if (EVP_PKEY_derive(ctxShared, NULL, &sharedKeyBufferSize) <= 0)
        return;

    // Allocate buffer for shared key
    unsigned char *sharedKeyBuffer = new unsigned char[sharedKeyBufferSize];
    if (sharedKeyBuffer == NULL)
        return;

    // Derive the shared key
    if (EVP_PKEY_derive(ctxShared, sharedKeyBuffer, &sharedKeyBufferSize) <= 0)
    {
        unsigned long error = ERR_get_error();
        cout << "Failed to derive shared key. Error code = " << error << std::endl;
        cout << ERR_reason_error_string(error) << std::endl;

        return;
    }

    // Free shared key context
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctxShared);

    // Create Base64 shared key string
    base64Encode(sharedKeyStr, sharedKeyBuffer, sharedKeyBufferSize);
}
```

The OpenSSL error output is as follows:

*Failed to add peer to shared key context. Error code = 101298329
different parameters*

How can it have different parameters when it was derived from a Context that was BASED on the parameters already existing in the original publicKey?

Comment: *(I know this is late, but it might help someone)* Are your keys EC by any chance? In that case you need to define a curve or name it, see EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag().